# What are attack vectors for attacking tethering smartphones?

Tags: wifi, mobile, wireless, smartphone

Are there any attack vectors for attacking tethered wireless networks (mobile hotspot), other than for normal wireless networks? Assuming the tethered wirless network uses state-of-the-art encryption+authentication (WPA2 with PSK).

Comment: there's a lot of different phones and flavors of the same model from different carriers that all have unique strengths and weaknesses. "normal wireless network" gear is much more secure because it does far less, has fewer entry points, has a lot less diversity, and has been tested to accomplish the goal of a safe hotspot.

Comment: @dandavis:   You should probably make it a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attack vectors remain the same. The only difference is that mobile phones might provide an additional attack surface with other services reachable like Bluetooth and GSM/UMTS/GPRS/...

Check public vulnerability databases for entries regarding WLAN or other network issues to determine the known attack surface of mobile devices. Once in a while there is something published. But the amount of mobile device specific issues is rather small.